# fancyBox is not called / HTTP response headers

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I want fancyBox 2.1 display a `div` on my site. I tried the examples from the download package:

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="fancybox" href="#inline1" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet">Inline</a></li>
    <li><a class="fancybox fancybox.ajax" href="ajax.txt">Ajax</a></li>
    <li><a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="iframe.html">Iframe</a></li>
    <li><a class="fancybox" href="http://www.adobe.com/jp/events/cs3_web_edition_tour/swfs/perform.swf">Swf</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="inline1" style="width:400px;display: none;">
    <h3>Etiam quis mi eu elit</h3>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum [...]
    </p>
</div>
```

I have included all the corresponding files. But fancyBox does not open if I click on the first link ("Inline"). I use a self-written PHP app, that generates HTML code. If I copy this generated HTML code 1:1 into a plain `.html` file, everything works fantastically. So the problem cannot correlate with my HTML code.

Does fancyBox take care of HTTP response headers or something like that?

Comment: `I use a self-written PHP app, that generates HTML code.` ... does the inline code exist when fancybox is called?

Comment: The problem was sending a `Content-type: application/xhtml+xml` header. Just solved it, but thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the mistake myself: The problem was sending `Content-type: application/xhtml+xml` in my header. Without it, or with a common `Content-type: text/html` one, fancyBox seems to work properly.